# Postman returns 415 when trying to do a POST using form-data, but the same request with JSON works fine

Tags: c#, json, postman, form-data, webapi

I'm building a REST API and testing it out using Postman. I have an end-point which works fine when I test it by sending in raw json data, but I want to expand on this endpoint and allow it to take both json data and accept a file, so I wanted to test my current endpoint without any modifications, and see if I would get back the same result when I test my API using form-data instead of JSON, but it always throws a 415 exception.

On this picture I make a request with form-data.

[image: Form-data request]

And here I make the request to the same endpoint but with json data

[image: JSON post data request]

Note that I have not added any customs headers when sending the requests, the (10) you see in the top is Temporary Headers. I also tried adding Content-Type: multipart/form-data, but got the same result.

Here's the code behind

**PeopleController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<PersonDto> PostPerson(PersonForCreationDto person)
    {
        var personEntity = _mapper.Map<Entities.Person>(person); //Maps PersonForCreationDto to Entites.Person. This is possible because of the mapping in PeopleProfile.cs
        _personLibraryRepositry.AddPerson(personEntity);
        _personLibraryRepositry.Save();

        var personToReturn = _mapper.Map<PersonDto>(personEntity);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetPerson",
            new { personId = personToReturn.PersonId },
            personToReturn);
    }
```

**PersonForCreationDto**

```
public class PersonForCreationDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string ReasonsForBeingOnTheList { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PictureForCreationDto> Pictures { get; set; }
            = new List<PictureForCreationDto>();


    }
```

**PersonLibraryRepository.cs**

```
 public void AddPerson(Person person)
    {
       if (person == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(person));
        }

        person.PersonId = Guid.NewGuid(); //API is responsibile for creating new IDS.

            foreach (var picture in person.Pictures)
            {
                picture.PictureId = Guid.NewGuid();

            }
        _context.People.Add(person);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form data, add this to the Headers

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Tried this aswell, did not help